# sibling's padding does not momentarily override parent's padding

Tags: css, padding

Why does #sibling show a padding = 1em, not 0em?

CSS:

```
#parent {
   padding: 1em;
}

#sibling {
   padding: 0em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">

<div id="sibling> ... stuff ... </div>

... more stuff ...

</div>
```

Is there a padding collapsing identical to margin collapsing???

Answer (score 0):

`#sibling` doesn't have a padding, at least not in the code you posted. You can use background colors to see it better:

```css
#parent {
  padding: 1em;
  background: green;
}

#sibling {
  padding: 0em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div id="sibling"> ... stuff ... </div>

... more stuff ...

</div>
```

(P.S.: You were missing a closing quote in your code)

Comment: (1) the missing quote was a typo here, not in my css ... sorry. (2) sibling does have a padding = 0, which is what I want it to be. sibling, rather, ignores padding = 0, and displays padding = 1, the padding of the parent. In short, I want to start with = 1, interrupt with = 0, and then after sibling, return to = 1. Again, sorry about my typo.

Comment: okay, with "doesn't have a padding" I meant zero padding. But the padding is definitely not 1em, as you were writing, but zero (?)

Comment: sibling registered 1, not 0. It registered the padding of its parent = 1, not its own = 0

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "registered" and where you get that from. Can you explain more?

Comment: If you inspect my snippet (= your code) using the browser developer tools and select `#sibling`, it has *no* padding, i.e. a padding setting of `0em`, which results in no padding at all.